# Unable to set_new_handler

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, new-operator

I am trying to learn new_handler in  C++
I have the following piece of code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<new>
using namespace std;

class A
{   
    new_handler O_Handler;
    static void NoMem()
    {
        cout<<"No more mem"<<endl;
        throw bad_alloc();
    }

    public: 
    void* operator new(size_t size) throw(bad_alloc)
    {
            cout<<"Custom handler called"<<endl;
            O_Handler=set_new_handler(NoMem);//set for current class
            void *pv=::operator new(size);
            set_new_handler(O_Handler);//restor
            return pv;
    }
    A()
    {
        cout<<"ctor"<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    //cout<A::_cnt;
    try{
        A *a[13];
        for(int i=0;i<13;++i)
            a[i]=new A();
    }
    catch(bad_alloc &e)
    {
        cout<<"Size to large"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However I am getting a compilation issue as below:

```
F:\prep\c++\overloading_new_operator_set_new_handler.cpp    In static member function 'static void* A::operator new(size_t)':
7   14  F:\prep\c++\overloading_new_operator_set_new_handler.cpp    [Error] invalid use of member 'A::O_Handler' in static member function
19  4   F:\prep\c++\overloading_new_operator_set_new_handler.cpp    [Error] from this location
7   14  F:\prep\c++\overloading_new_operator_set_new_handler.cpp    [Error] invalid use of member 'A::O_Handler' in static member function
21  20  F:\prep\c++\overloading_new_operator_set_new_handler.cpp    [Error] from this location
```

I haven't declared `new` as `static`.
What is the reason for this and how to solve??

Comment: `operator new` is per-class; it's implicitly `static`. The object that would be `*this` doesn't exist yet; it's this function's responsibility to prepare the memory that it's going to be created in.

Comment: any suggestions how to solve this issue??

Comment: Use a local variable instead of a member variable.